# How to get DecodeBytes() output without canonical extended JSON additions

Tags: mongodb, go

I use `DecodeBytes()` function to get the data from mongoDB (as the struct of the data can varies) with mongo-driver for Go.
My problem is when one of the values is int/double (and not string).
 In that case it add adds some stuff of canonical extended JSON, for example `3` to `"$numberDouble": "3.0"`.

How can I remove those additions of the canonical extended JSON?

```
func (m *Mongoclient) Find(collection string, filter interface{}) string {
    findResult := m.Db.Collection(collection).FindOne(m.Ctx, filter)
    if findResult.Err() != nil {
        fmt.Println(findResult.Err().Error())
        return ""
    }
    db, err := findResult.DecodeBytes()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return ""
    }
    return db.String()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `Decode` function to `bson.M` and than `json.Marshal` it:

```
    var document bson.M
    err := findResult.Decode(&document)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return ""
    }
    resBytes, err := json.Marshal(document)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return ""
    }
    return string(resBytes)
```